# Problem defining multiple HTML tooltips using jQuery Tools

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tools

I'm trying to create a HTML tooltip for each row in table using jQuery Tools. I thought it would be very easy because I'd be able to use a syntax like this:

```
 $("#myTable tr").tooltip({
    tip: "#tooltip" + $(this).attr("id")
  });
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me firstly why it doesn't work and secondly how I can initialise multiple HTML tooltips without using an each() statement?

[Check out this fiddle for a full example](http://jsfiddle.net/philjhale/tEWZF/7/)

Comment: You shouldn't set the id attribute to just a number.

Comment: I've only done that to make the example code as simple as possible

Comment: Here is the same question with answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301536/jquery-tools-tooltip-jquery-reference-to-this-attribute?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you should only use the `tip` option when you want to manually give a single tooltip to multiple elements. Otherwise you should use the default tooltip by adding a `title` attribute to each of your elements.

Secondly, it doesn't work because `$(this)` doesn't refer to the `<tr>` so the `.attr("id")` fails. If you want it to refer to the `<tr>`, you have to use `each()`.

Comment: Oh this is specific to jQuery Tools. The tooltip plugin uses the title attribute to generate the tooltip. This is independent of the alt-text.

Comment: The problem is I can't use the title attribute because it doesn't allow me to include HTML

Comment: Do you know why $(this) doesn't refer to the <tr> element? It kinda seems like it should. Unless I'm missing something 'this' typically refers to the element matched by the selector

Comment: Why not? `title="<b>My tooltip</b>"` should work if you're using jQuery Tools.

Comment: You're spot on, I never thought of that. Unfortunately it's not ideal if I want to display a lot of information in my tooltip

Comment: Putting html into the title attribute is invalid.