# jQuery Tools: Tooltip, jQuery reference to "this" attribute

Tags: jquery, tooltip, selector, jquery-tools

I'm implementing a Tooltip for cells within  table and I need to be able to grab the target's `data-message` attribute.

```
$("#pricing_plans_table .sku_tooltip").tooltip({

        // each trashcan image works as a trigger
        tip: '#' + $(this).attr('data-message'),

        // move tooltip a little bit to the right
        offset: [0, 15],

        // there is no delay when the mouse is moved away from the trigger
        delay: 0
    });
```

That doesn't work. I get "Cannot find tooltip for [object Object]" ... I'm not quite sure how to reference the target correctly.

Comment: this all looks correct, can we see the html as well?

Comment: console.log `$(this).attr('data-message')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `this` inside a map like that. Try:

```
$("#pricing_plans_table .sku_tooltip").each(function(i,el) {
    var tipstr = $(this).attr('data-message');
    $(this).tooltip({
        tip: '#' + tipstr,
        offset: [0, 15],
        delay: 0
    });    
});
```

Comment: You can use `this` inside a map all you want, as long as you're aware of what `this` refers to.  In this instance, the OP thought `this` would refer to the object that he called `tooltip` against when it instead refers to whatever `this` is in the outer context.  Just a clarification: `this` is perfectly valid, you just need to know what `this` is!

Comment: @Chad Not quite, see comments on AdamTerlson's answer.

Comment: I was under the impression there was a single item he was assigning to; that's my misinterpretation. I removed my comments.

Comment: So using a class and assigning "tooltip" to that class isn't actually the best way to go for multiple tooltips.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you do this inside the `tooltip` plugin however you can use an `.each()` loop to get the value and initialize the `tooltip` plugin for each element (internally this is all the plugin probably does anyway):

```
$("#pricing_plans_table .sku_tooltip").each(function (index, value) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.tooltip({
        tip    : '#' + $this.attr('data-message'),
        offset : [0, 15],
        delay  : 0

    });
});
```

Comment: @Chad The reason to use an `.each()` loop is to assign the correct `data-message` attribute to the correct `tooltip` instance. How do you do that otherwise?

Comment: I was under the impression there was a single item he was assigning to; that's my misinterpretation. I removed my comments.

Comment: Chad made the same assumption I did: that this was a single element. Instead, the OP seems to be trying to create multiple tooltips.